# using Axiom of Completeness to find the root of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

set A={x:^11+7^5+√5·^3+8<2}
Prove that the number sup is a root of the function ()=^11+7^5+√5·^3+8−2 without using any differentiation and intermediate value theorem.

I want to know how to solve this problem using Axiom of Completeness and existence of square roots. Like the aim is to prove f(supA)>=0 and f(supA)>=0 so that we can conclude that f(supA)=0… or we can just ruling out the possibilities f(supA)>0  and f(supA)<0 ??  can anyone tell me the steps? thx!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).